# Equivalent of emacs open line C-o

Tags: key-bindings

In Emacs, `C-o` or `M-x open-line` creates a blank new line under the point/cursor without moving it.

Since `c-l` isn't used in insert mode and I like I have the following two lines in my `.vimrc`.

```
" C-o from emacs (open line at current point)
inoremap <c-o> <esc><esc>mpA<cr><esc><esc>`pa
" make C-l do C-o's job
inoremap <c-l> <c-o>
```

This mapping has a number of drawbacks

- It clobbers whatever is in the `p` register
- If I use the `c-o` binding when my cursor is at the beginning of the line, after executing `c-o` my cursor is at position 1 instead of position 0.
- I have `set so=7` so that I always see seven lines around my cursor if possible. If I'm near the bottom of this window invoking `c-o` counts as cursor movement

Is there a way of adding a new line below the cursor without changing its position or using a register?

Comment: are you looking for `:inoremap <silent> <c-o> <c-o>:call append('.',"")<cr>`? Note: I woudln't recommend mapping <c-o> away.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes that's perfect! I decided to map that command to `<c-l>` instead based on your warning.

Comment: The [unimpaired plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) might be of your interest, where `[<space>` and `]<space>` put a blank line before/after the cursorline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try a vimscript function

```
function NewLine()
    let l:position = getcurpos()
    normal o
    call cursor(l:position[1], l:position[2])
endfunction
```

you can then map it to  with

```
inoremap <silent> <c-l> <c-o>:call NewLine()<cr>
```